# Parsing 'multipart/alternative' content-type

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime, multipart

I am using javamail api to get unread messages from inbox folder, the problem is i am getting odd content-type `'multipart/alternative'` when i call `Message.getContentType()`.
Also when i down-cast content of message(from `Object`) to class `Multipart` i get an exception 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.classCastException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPInputStream cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart at............`

I just want to get the content of email and store it in DB.

```
        subject  = messages[j].getSubject();                                
        System.out.println(messages[j].getContentType());
        if(messages[j].getContent() instanceof Multipart)
        {                                  
            Multipart mime = (Multipart) messages[j].getContent();

            for (int i = 0; i < mime.getCount(); i++)
            {
                BodyPart part = mime.getBodyPart(i);
                content += part.getContent().toString();
            }
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java mail with attachment: ClassCastException on javax.mail.Multipart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594206/java-mail-with-attachment-classcastexception-on-javax-mail-multipart)

Comment: I've just posted the answer that my be related - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15729766/1102014).

Answer (score 1):

Multiplart/alternative is not odd; in fact, it's very common.  It's typically used by email clients to create 2 versions of the same message, one that is plain text and the other that is HTML.  First, your email client must detect that the message is multipart/alternative, which it can do by finding these headers in the headers section:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=some-boundary
```

Second, it must parse each of the alternative body parts, examine their headers to see which one (or ones) that it wants to process, and then do so.

```
--some-boundary
Content-Type: text/plain

...The plain text version of the email goes here...

--some-boundary
Content-Type: text/html

<html>...The html version of the content goes here...</html>

--some-boundary--
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into the same problem described [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2369993&tstart=0).

Note that multipart/alternative is a perfectly normal type, as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpa).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem while I was to read message attachments using Android JavaMail. I have fixed this error by adding following lines of code. There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. This resolved my problem. Hope it helps someone out there.

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

Cheers!